# Django model save method, updating m2m does not work

Tags: python, django, django-models, m2m

I need to prevent user from self-killing from administrators list in the model:

```
class Organization(models.Model):       
    administrators = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, null=True, help_text=_('Administrators are people that manage the organization'))

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # --- some specific code here ---
        super(Organization, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.user_id not in self.administrators.values_list('id', flat=True):
            self.administrators.add(self.user)
            # super(Organization, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            self.save()                
            # assert False, self.administrators.all() # <- it works, if assert goes here
```

Ok, it might be some black magic casted here, let's try a `post_save` signal:

```
def organization_post_save(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if instance.user_id not in instance.administrators.all().values_list('id', flat=True):
        instance.administrators.add(instance.user)
        instance.save()
        # assert False, '?'
```

It adds a user in the administrators list only if assertion occures. Ok, may be black magic  occured again, let's try:

```
def organization_m2m_changed(sender, instance, action, reverse, model, pk_set, using, **kwargs):
    if instance.user_id not in instance.administrators.all().values_list('id', flat=True):
        instance.administrators.add(instance.user_id)

m2m_changed.connect(organization_m2m_changed, sender=Organization.administrators.through)
```

Of course, `maximum recursion depth exceeded`. What's wrong? This pain is unstoppable :(

## UPD1

It seems, that `post_save` method called **BEFORE** m2m relations saved, so it ran into a race condition, and a new data was replaced with form data, that was empty. Here is a bad solution:

```
def organization_m2m_changed(sender, instance, action, reverse, model, pk_set, using, **kwargs):

    if not instance.administrators.filter(id=instance.user_id).exists():
        if action.startswith('post_'):
            instance.administrators.add(instance.user)
```

Now i'd like to know what signal Django emits after **ALL** work about a model done?

P.S. No magic. :(

## UPD2 lie-ryan

**forms.py**

```
class OrganizationEditForm(forms.ModelForm):    
    class Meta:
        model = Organization
        exclude = ['user']
        widgets = floppyforms_widgets(Organization)
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def edit_organization(request, organization_id=None):
    user = request.user
    c = Context({'user': user})

    instance = get_object_or_404(Organization, id=organization_id) if organization_id else Organization(user=user)
    form = OrganizationEditForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=instance)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, _('Organization saved successfully'))
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('organizations'))

    c['form'] = form
    c['instance'] = instance

    return render_to_response('cat/edit_organization.html', c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: `self.user_id not in self.administrators.values_list('id', flat=True)` can better be written as `not self.administrators.filter(id=self.user_id).exists()`.

Comment: There is no race condition possible, Django signals don't spawn a new thread, Django signal is processed in the main thread sequentially.

Comment: Lie Ryan, yeah, there's no race condition, i mean this case: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#updating-attributes-based-on-existing-fields

or 

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/queries/#avoiding-race-conditions-using-f

It just looks like changes on m2m in post_save() was killed by a django's built-in m2m save method.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting recursion error because you're calling self.save() inside of Organization.save(). Don't do this, if you want to save while overriding the save(),  call the superclass' version of save() instead of your own save().

Before adding an instance to an m2m relationship, both sides of the relationship must already have a primary key (i.e. already inserted to the db).  This means you can't add an unsaved, uncreated object to an m2m relationship.

Do this:

```
organisation.save()
user.save()
organisation.administrators.add(user)
```

I'd recommend doing this inside the View or Form since it is quite unexpected if a model's save method saved the user's model as well (though it should work inside the model's save() as well)

Comment: I think I should not get the recursion, because `save()` method called *only* `if instance.user_id not in ...`. It occures only because `administrators.add()` method did nothing. 

In any case, i cannot understand why first two ways does not work.

Comment: @lilo.panic: If instance.user_id is None (which is what you'd get if user isn't created yet) then you'll essentially be doing administrators.add(None) and get the recursion.

Comment: @lilo.panic: btw, you don't need to call instance.save() again after adding into instance.administrators.add(). Think about what really happens in the database level, an m2m relationship is stored in the through table, not in the Organisation or User table.

Comment: i see, `save()` method - was an overkill for testing. And `user_id` was **not** `None`, it was instance editing.

Comment: also, self.user probably don't contain the current user. You'll need to pass in request.user if that's what you want to do?

Comment: `post_save` called after model saved, so user exists in an instance, i've checked it with assertion in `save()`, `post_save()`, `m2m_changed`, be sure. Also, user field cannot be null, that field is required.

Comment: @lilo.panic: it's the ModelForm class that's replacing the data. The ModelForm class does two step save() when saving a model with m2m relationship, i.e. it first calls form.instance.save() and then form.save_m2m() which adds or remove users from the through table. Check out ModelForm.save() source code for details. It's rarely a good idea to override model.save(), you generally should do these changes in the form or the view class.